# Why do the aliens leave the body of their leader on Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, seaquest

In the second episode of the second season of *Seaquest DSV*, entitled *The Fear that Follows*, why exactly do the aliens leave the frozen, dead body of their leader on Earth?